# How to use manually installed python for personal programs without breaking any other application?

Tags: python

Hi I'm new to ubuntu and I have the following problem:

I'm aware that ubuntu comes with a python version, but I'm running in a web host and I 
don't have the `sudo` command and I only have access to my `/home/user`

I installed python 2.7.5 on my home, but when I try to do the easy_install command, it goes to `/usr/bin/python`

How can I do to use the python installed on my `/home` and not the one in the `/usr/bin/`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your best bet is to use an alias. Open your `~/.bash_aliases` file and type the following:

```
alias python='/path/to/python/in/your/home/directory'
```

with the `'`. For example, if your python binary file is `/home/user/Documents/bin/python`, the alias would be:

```
alias python='/home/user/Documents/bin/python'
```

This would not break existing application, since they would continue to use whatever version is `/usr/bin/python` or `/usr/bin/python3` and you would use the python stored in your home directory.

For easy_install to install modules to a specific directory, you can use the `--install-dir` option together with the `$PYTHONPATH` environment variable. To do this, do the following:

```
export PYTHONPATH='/home/user/python/lib/
```

and then

```
easy_install --install-dir /home/user/python/lib/ <module_to_install>
```

or whatever path you want to give to easy_install to install the modules.

Comment: Thanks, this solve my problem, but another one appeared because I would like to use easy_install and this is still going to /user/bin but I'm not sure if the version I have installed of python comes with easy_install, anyway the easy_install it is still going to /usr/bin

Comment: @ocespedes: Edited my answer to reflect that.

Comment: Is it `/home/user/python_lib/` or `/home/user/python/lib/`. You have used both in your answer. Moreover, we may also create an alias for `easy_install` so that we do not need to type that long command everytime.

Comment: @Aditya: I didn't mean to introduce an ambiguity but the user could create and add any arbitrary folder name. Thanks for pointing that out.